# Bootstrap Progress bar circle not responsive all of devises

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Im added my  web site for progress bar circle, its not responsive, all of devices are same size, i want to make this circle small devices are small  size and large devices are large size  , how can i make it correctly

Im all ready added  add  for this  (**responsive viewport meta**) in    `<head>` area

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

how to fix this issue

thanks

```css
.page {
    margin: 0px;
}

h1{
    margin: 40px 0 60px 0;
}

.dark-area {
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 -40px 20px -40px;
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after {content: " "; display: table;}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {*zoom: 1;}
.rect-auto,
.
.c100.p100 .slice {
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie,
.c100 .bar,

.c100.p98 .fill,
.c100.p99 .fill,
.c100.p100 .fill {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0.08em solid #01bb67;
    width: 0.84em;
    height: 0.84em;
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.pie-fill,

.c100.p100 .fill {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 120px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.0em 0.0em 0;
    background-color: #53585f;
}
.c100 *,
.c100 *:before,
.c100 *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.c100.center {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.c100.big {
    font-size: 180px;
}
.c100.small {
    font-size: 80px;
}
.c100 > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 4.5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    font-size: 0.2em;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.c100:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.08em;
    left: 0.08em;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 0.84em;
    height: 0.84em;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
.c100 .slice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}
.c100.p1 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3.6deg);
    transform: rotate(3.6deg);
}
.c100.p2 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(7.2deg);
    transform: rotate(7.2deg);
}
.c100.p3 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(10.8deg);
    transform: rotate(10.8deg);
}
.c100.p4 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(14.4deg);
    transform: rotate(14.4deg);
}
.c100.p5 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(18deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(18deg);
    transform: rotate(18deg);
}
.c100.p6 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(21.6deg);
    transform: rotate(21.6deg);
}
.c100.p7 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(25.2deg);
    transform: rotate(25.2deg);
}
.c100.p8 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(28.8deg);
    transform: rotate(28.8deg);
}
.c100.p9 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(32.4deg);
    transform: rotate(32.4deg);
}
.c100.p10 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(36deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(36deg);
    transform: rotate(36deg);
}
.c100.p11 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(39.6deg);
    transform: rotate(39.6deg);
}
.c100.p12 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
    transform: rotate(43.2deg);
}
.c100.p13 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
    transform: rotate(46.800000000000004deg);
}
.c100.p14 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(50.4deg);
    transform: rotate(50.4deg);
}
.c100.p15 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(54deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(54deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(54deg);
    transform: rotate(54deg);
}
.c100.p16 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(57.6deg);
    transform: rotate(57.6deg);
}
.c100.p17 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(61.2deg);
    transform: rotate(61.2deg);
}
.c100.p18 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(64.8deg);
    transform: rotate(64.8deg);
}
.c100.p19 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(68.4deg);
    transform: rotate(68.4deg);
}
.c100.p20 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(72deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(72deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(72deg);
    transform: rotate(72deg);
}
.c100.p21 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
    transform: rotate(75.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p22 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(79.2deg);
    transform: rotate(79.2deg);
}
.c100.p23 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(82.8deg);
    transform: rotate(82.8deg);
}
.c100.p24 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(86.4deg);
    transform: rotate(86.4deg);
}
.c100.p25 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.c100.p26 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
    transform: rotate(93.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p27 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(97.2deg);
    transform: rotate(97.2deg);
}
.c100.p28 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(100.8deg);
    transform: rotate(100.8deg);
}
.c100.p29 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(104.4deg);
    transform: rotate(104.4deg);
}
.c100.p30 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(108deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(108deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(108deg);
    transform: rotate(108deg);
}
.c100.p31 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
    transform: rotate(111.60000000000001deg);
}
.c100.p32 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(115.2deg);
    transform: rotate(115.2deg);
}
.c100.p33 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(118.8deg);
    transform: rotate(118.8deg);
}
.c100.p34 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(122.4deg);
    transform: rotate(122.4deg);
}
.c100.p35 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(126deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(126deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(126deg);
    transform: rotate(126deg);
}
.c100.p36 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(129.6deg);
    transform: rotate(129.6deg);
}
.c100.p37 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
    transform: rotate(133.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p38 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(136.8deg);
    transform: rotate(136.8deg);
}
.c100.p39 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(140.4deg);
    transform: rotate(140.4deg);
}
.c100.p40 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(144deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(144deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(144deg);
    transform: rotate(144deg);
}
.c100.p41 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(147.6deg);
    transform: rotate(147.6deg);
}
.c100.p42 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
    transform: rotate(151.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p43 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(154.8deg);
    transform: rotate(154.8deg);
}
.c100.p44 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(158.4deg);
    transform: rotate(158.4deg);
}
.c100.p45 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(162deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(162deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(162deg);
    transform: rotate(162deg);
}
.c100.p46 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(165.6deg);
    transform: rotate(165.6deg);
}
.c100.p47 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
    transform: rotate(169.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p48 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(172.8deg);
    transform: rotate(172.8deg);
}
.c100.p49 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(176.4deg);
    transform: rotate(176.4deg);
}
.c100.p50 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.c100.p51 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(183.6deg);
    transform: rotate(183.6deg);
}
.c100.p52 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
    transform: rotate(187.20000000000002deg);
}
.c100.p53 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(190.8deg);
    transform: rotate(190.8deg);
}
.c100.p54 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(194.4deg);
    transform: rotate(194.4deg);
}
.c100.p55 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(198deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(198deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(198deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(198deg);
    transform: rotate(198deg);
}
.c100.p56 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(201.6deg);
    transform: rotate(201.6deg);
}
.c100.p57 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
    transform: rotate(205.20000000000002deg);
}



.c100:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
/*
.c100:hover > span {
    width: 3.33em;
    line-height: 3.33em;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    color: #000000;
}*/
.c100:hover:after {
    top: 0.04em;
    left: 0.04em;
    width: 0.92em;
    height: 0.92em;
}
.c100.dark {
    background-color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark .bar,
.c100.dark .fill {
    border-color: #c6ff00 !important;
}
.c100.dark > span {
    color: #777777;
}
.c100.dark:after {
    background-color: #666666;
}
.c100.dark:hover > span {
    color: #c6ff00;
}
.c100.green .bar,
.c100.green .fill {
    border-color: #4db53c !important;
}
.c100.green:hover > span {
    color: #4db53c;
}
.c100.green.dark .bar,
.c100.green.dark .fill {
    border-color: #5fd400 !important;
}
.c100.green.dark:hover > span {
    color: #5fd400;
}
.c100.orange .bar,
.c100.orange .fill {
    border-color: #dd9d22 !important;
}
.c100.orange:hover > span {
    color: #dd9d22;
}
.c100.orange.dark .bar,
.c100.orange.dark .fill {
    border-color: #e08833 !important;
}
.c100.orange.dark:hover > span {
    color: #e08833;
}
span.prstg {position: absolute;

    z-index: 1;
    left: 4.5rem;
    top: 2rem;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    font-size: 0.1em;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;

    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<div class="row"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="page">

        <!-- default -->
        <div class="clearfix">

            <div class="c100 p48 big">
                <span>48</span><span class="prstg">%</span>
                <div class="slice">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="fill"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css there is a media-query where you can reduce the size of the section according to the device width [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: In your css there is a class called .c100.big reduce the font-size according to the device width.. Example @media only screen and (min-width: 768px)  
 { ..c100.big{ font-size:108px;}}

Comment: sir  can you please make it, its big help for me , my university finale project for this

Comment: at media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 520px) { .c100.big{ font-size:100px;}} and .. this is for mobile -> at media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) { .c100.big{ font-size:50px;}} (at means @)

Comment: not working sir,  i put  like this `@media only screen and  (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 520px) { .c100.big{ font-size:200px;}}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) { .c100.big{ font-size:50px;}}`

Comment: can u make a screenshot??

Comment: sir its mobile and tab let are working,  up to 15 inch display are small this circle like 1024*802 and 1440*802

Comment: Ok...let's make it simple, increase the font-size in the normal css from 180px to 200px(not in media-query)....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157382/discussion-between-core114-and-saravana-priyan-s).